# How do I remove "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" in GRUB menu?

Tags: grub2

How would I remove "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" in the GRUB menu?

This is what I see in the GRUB menu:

```
Ubuntu 
Advanced Options for Ubuntu 
OpenSUSE 
Advanced Options for OpenSUSE 
CentOS 
Advanced Options for CentOS
```

---

I want my GRUB to look like:

```
Ubuntu
OpenSUSE
CentOS
```

---

I am using these command to remove memtest86:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
sudo update-grub
```

and it is working, but I cannot find any command to remove the Advanced Options menu.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a GUI using `grub-customizer`.

Upon opening the program, it will present the current set of menu options:

[image]

A right-click on a menu line will allow you to move that line up or down, rename the menu entry, or delete the menu entry to suite your needs.

Grub-Customizer can be obtained via PPA at https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer

Comment: yes i am sure , i can recover my last back up from Grub file after test it , now how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok the trick is to edit the `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` file remove the right template entries that generates that option in grub menu:

```
 # TRANSLATORS: %s is replaced with an OS name
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%    echo "submenu '$(gettext_printf "Advanced options for %s" "${OS}" | grub_quote)' \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-$boot_device_id' {" 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
is_top_level=false
  fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" advanced \
%              "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}"
%  for supported_init in ${SUPPORTED_INITS}; do
%    init_path="${supported_init#*:}"
%    if [ -x "${init_path}" ] && [ "$(readlink -f /sbin/init)" != "${init_path}" ]; then
%      linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" "init-${supported_init%%:*}" \
%         "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT} init=${init_path}"
%    fi
%  done
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  if [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY}" != "xtrue" ]; then
    linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" recovery \
                "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX}"
  fi

  list=`echo $list | tr ' ' '\n' | fgrep -vx "$linux" | tr '\n' ' '`
done
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%# If at least one kernel was found, then we need to       
%# add a closing '}' for the submenu command.              
%if [ x"$is_top_level" != xtrue ]; then                    
%  echo '}'                                                   
%fi                                                        
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
echo "$title_correction_code"
```

Now note the `%` characters used, I used them to surround the lines that should be removed from that file to get the `Advanced options for Ubuntu` grub menu not to display, they aren't part of the original file. These lines exists from `345` down that file. **Again all within that enclosure should be removed, compare to your own `10_linux` file**!

After that edit open the `/etc/default/grub` file and add the following line to it:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true
```

Now run `sudo update-grub`

**Acid Test**:

Run `sudo update-grub` and if the output is ok and you can see your boot images then most likely it's ok, but please backup and heed to my warning stated below.

**WARNING**:

Edit with care, I would suggest several methods:

1. Make a backup copy before editing

   - Then edit that backup copy and make sure it's like what I have here.
2. Use a Virtual machine to test it out first.
3. Tested on a Virtual machine

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I removed **Advanced Options for ...** by adding lines

```
 GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
 GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y
```

in the file `/etc/default/grub` and then running

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: but this doesn't produce the desired result - it just dumps all the stuff that was in **Advanced Options** into the main menu it seems

Comment: try again by adding GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

Comment: hmm nope it's still there

Comment: are you sure you apply the changes to the right /etc/default/grub file? In my system there are two ubuntu installations, and I did the changes in the first installation. second installed ubuntu system is default boot option but have to do the changes in first installation's /etc/default/grub file. and don't forget to run update-grub command.

Comment: I only have one OS on my machine... and yeah I ran update-grub... and the system complained about an error (which may have been coincidental)